# wprintf format type specification %ws

Tags: c++, format, printf

I just discovered that %ws was common knowledge (to some), for formatting unicode strings, as is %wZ - however msdn does not document these in a place I can find them. There are many people who write about these usefull printf format types individually on the web, but no official catch-all that I can find, and hence learn that they exist.

What I'm really after is help writting mistake-free formatter code since I have in places got a mix of %s and %S and want to clean these up as far possible. I am unable to control compilation of certain shared code and toolchain scripts of the project, so I am seeking a 'canonical' article that sorts the MS spec apart from the STD spec a little.

Comment: You should consider dumping `printf` in favor of `iostream`.

Comment: All of the contributions are great. Especially the possibility to improve code readability through artfully use of iostream. Will think over who gets my first stackoverflow correct answer till tomorrow. I would love it if there was a complete web reference, not that the 2 answers aren't correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an ideal world the list of valid types [on MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w.aspx) would be complete.  It does mention that some are Microsoft extensions.

However, there is also separate info on [wsprintf formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647550%28VS.85%29.aspx), which includes `ws` and `ls` as you  noted.

I don't see any other type lists that apply here on MSDN.

As noted in comments, I do think your life would be easier if you left the CRT behind and moved to use `iostream`, but I am sure that may not be immediately practical. In general, widespread usage of CRT in what's intended to be C++ code is a cause for suspicion.

Comment: I've checked your recommended wsprintf documentation, but it doesn't include ws. Did Microsoft remove it meanwhile?

Comment: @Lorlin - the build date on that page is 10/27/2012 so it looks like they've removed that reference, as you guessed.